# LearnYouNode - Jugglling Async (#9) - I Must be Missing Something

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

There seem to be many questions about this problem out here, but none directly relate to my question AFAICT.  Here is the problem statement:

> This problem is the same as the previous problem (HTTP COLLECT) in that you need to use http.get(). However, this time you will be provided with three URLs as the first three command-line arguments.
>
> You must collect the complete content provided to you by each of the URLs and print it to the console (stdout). You don't need to print out the length, just the data as a String; one line per URL. The catch is that you must print them out in the same order as the URLs are provided to you as command-line arguments.

Here is my original solution that fails:

```
var http = require('http')
var concat = require('concat-stream')

var args = process.argv.slice(2, 5)
var args_len = args.length
var results = []

args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
    http.get(arg, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8')
        res.pipe(concat(function(str) {
            results[i] = str
            if (results.length === args_len)
                results.forEach(function(val) {
                    console.log(val)
                })
        }))
    }).on('error', console.error)
})
```

This is the solution they recommend:

```
var http = require('http')
var bl = require('bl')
var results = []
var count = 0

function printResults () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    console.log(results[i])
}

function httpGet (index) {
  http.get(process.argv[2 + index], function (response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
      if (err)
        return console.error(err)

      results[index] = data.toString()
      count++

      if (count == 3)
        printResults()
    }))
  })
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  httpGet(i)
```

What I fail to grok is the fundamental difference between my code and the official solution.  I am doing the same as their solution when it comes to stuffing the replies into an array to reference later. They use a counter to count the number of callbacks while I am comparing the length of two arrays (one whose length increases every callback); does that matter?  When I try my solution outside the bounds of the `learnyounode` program it seems to work just fine.  But I know that probably means little....  So someone who knows node better than I... care to explain where I have gone wrong?  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They use a counter to count the number of callbacks while I am comparing the length of two arrays (one whose length increases every callback); does that matter?

Yes, it does matter. The [`.length` of an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) depends on the highest index in the array, not the actual number of assigned elements.

The difference surfaces only when the results from the asynchronous requests come back *out of order*. If you first assign index `0`, then `1`, then `2` and so on, the `.length` matches the number of assigned elements and would be the same as their `count`er. But now try out this:

```
var results = []
console.log(results.length) // 0 - as expected
results[1] = "lo ";
console.log(results.length) // 2 - sic!
results[0] = "Hel";
console.log(results.length) // 2 - didn't change!
results[3] = "ld!";
console.log(results.length) // 4
results[2] = "Wor";
console.log(results.length) // 4
```

If you would test the length after each assignment and output the array whenever you get `4`, it would print

```
"Hello ld!"
"Hello World!"
```

Comment: Interesting... that is a total land mine there and is not something I would have expected.  Turns out that is one of two issues.  The other issue has to do with the scoping of the `i` variable.  I will answer this in more detail below.

Comment: Was incorrect about the `i` comment above.  Using a counter solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there were two different issues here, one of which was pointed out by @Bergi above.  The two issues are as follows:

- The `.length` method does not actually return the number of elements in the array.  Rather it returns the highest index that is available.  This seems quite silly.  Thanks to @Bergi for pointing this out.
- The scoping of the `i` variable is improper, and as such the value of `i` can change.  This causes a race condition when results come back.

My final solution ended up being as follows:

```
var http = require('http')
var concat = require('concat-stream')

var args = process.argv.slice(2, 5)
var args_len = args.length
var results = []
var count = 0

function get_url_save(url, idx) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8')
        res.pipe(concat(function(str) {
            results[idx] = str
            if (++count === args_len)
                results.forEach(function(val) {
                    console.log(val)
                })
        }))
    }).on('error', console.error)
}

args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
    get_url_save(arg, i)
})
```

Breaking the outtermost `forEach` into a method call solves the changing `i` issue since `i` gets passed in as parameter by value, thus never changing.  The addition of the counter solves the issue described by @Bergi since the `.length` method isn't as intuitive as one would imagine.

Comment: No, there is no problem with the `i` variable in your original code. It already is in the function scope of the `forEach` callback, creating a new variable for every iteration. You never assign to it, so it does *not* change and there is no race condition. The only race condition is when the requests come back out of order, so e.g. first the one with `i=0` then `i=2` then `i=1`, but still each `i` is bound to the respective `arg`.

Comment: In your new code, you could equally do `arg.forEach(get_url_save)`, which shows how this is equivalent to the solution with the anonymous callback.

Comment: Ah... you are correct.  So if I had been using a for loop with a variable then it would have been an issue, but since I was using the `forEach` it put it in function scope which made it sane.

Comment: Yes, exactly that.